Pitch Detection - Yin algorithm problem on ESP32
I am currently developing a tuner using ESP32. My goal is to determine the pitch of a piece of sound data that I collect from a microphone. To do so I decided to use the Yin algorithm. I got the implementation from GitHub: https://github.com/DingKe/Yin-Pitch-Tracking/blob/master/Yin.c
/**
 * Runs the Yin pitch detection algorithm
 * @param  yin    Initialized Yin object
 * @param  buffer Buffer of samples to analyze
 * @return        Fundamental frequency of the signal in Hz. Returns -1 if pitch can't be found
 */
float Yin_getPitch(Yin *yin, int16_t* buffer){
    int16_t tauEstimate = -1;
    float pitchInHertz = -1;
    
    /* Step 1: Calculates the squared difference of the signal with a shifted version of itself. */
    Yin_difference(yin, buffer);
    
    /* Step 2: Calculate the cumulative mean on the normalized difference calculated in step 1 */
    Yin_cumulativeMeanNormalizedDifference(yin);
    
    /* Step 3: Search through the normalized cumulative mean array and find values that are over the threshold */
    tauEstimate = Yin_absoluteThreshold(yin);
    
    /* Step 5: Interpolate the shift value (tau) to improve the pitch estimate. */
    if(tauEstimate != -1){
        pitchInHertz = YIN_SAMPLING_RATE / Yin_parabolicInterpolation(yin, tauEstimate);
    }
    
    return pitchInHertz;
}

That is the implementation of the method that returns the pitch. You can see the details if you want at GitHub.
The algorithm is parameterized with this
#define YIN_SAMPLING_RATE 8000
witch is the rate at witch I sample the microphone input, which I do as follows:
const uint16_t samples = 4096; //This value MUST ALWAYS be a power of 2
double samplingFrequency = YIN_SAMPLING_RATE;
unsigned int  sampling_period_us = round(1000000*(1.0/samplingFrequency));
long time = micros();
for(int i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
  time = micros();

  vReal[i] = analogRead(35);

  while(micros() - time < sampling_period_us);
}

The problem is that the algorithm seems to be dependent of the sampling rate I define. If YIN_SAMPLING_RATE = 8000 the frequency I get is more or less accurate, but if I make this value higher or lower the algorithm stops working.
I have no idea what's wrong with my code
I've tried changing the buffer size, normalizing the microphone input, but neither work.

Just guessing, but I think it may be an inconsistency between your sample rate and the number of samples in the buffer. The number of samples must be present in the fields bufferSize and halfBufferSize of the yin struct that you pass to Yin_getPitch(). The call to this function is missing in your sample.
